# Adding a new task for todo with render function react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to use true and false boolean to render the edit button for my todo list in react.

My thought is if edit button is clicked -> editing == true --> show renderEditing(). If editing is false show renderNormal().

Now when user clicks edit, it shows the renderEdit() page but however, all list is also showing the textform.. see image

[image]

Here is renderEditing() code which i think is the issue...

```
renderEditing() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>My awesome todo list</h1>
          <label htmlFor="newTodoDescription">Add Todo</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.newTodoDescription}
            name="newTodoDescription"
            id="newTodoDescription"
            onChange={this.handleOnChange}
          />
          <button onClick={this.handleAddTodo}>+</button>

          <ul>
          {this.state.todos.map(todo => {

            return (
              <li
                onClick={() => this.handleTodoClick(todo)}
                id= {todo.id}
                >

                {todo.description}

      <textarea ref ="editTodoDescription"
defaultValue = {this.state.todo}
name= "editTodoDescription"
id ="editTodoDescription"
></textarea>


                <button onClick={() => this.handleSave(todo)} > save 
</button>          
</li>


            );
          }

          )
          }
          </ul>


        </div>
      ); 
}
```

updated textarea value to todo but when i click edit for one button, two are still showing up...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`this.state.todo` does not exist. Simply set defaultValue to `todo`

```
  renderEditing() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My awesome todo list</h1>
        <label htmlFor="newTodoDescription">Add Todo</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.newTodoDescription}
          name="newTodoDescription"
          id="newTodoDescription"
          onChange={this.handleOnChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleAddTodo}>+</button>

        <ul>
          {this.state.todos.map(todo => {
            return (
              <li onClick={() => this.handleTodoClick(todo)} id={todo.id}>

                <textarea
                  ref="editTodoDescription"
                  defaultValue={todo.description}
                  name="editTodoDescription"
                  id="editTodoDescription"
                />

                <button onClick={() => this.handleSave(todo)}> save</button>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: it is still showing two text areas when edited. do u know what could be the reason?

Comment: Two textareas for each item?

Comment: yes when i click one edit button two text areas show up

Comment: In the screenshot I can only see on textarea per item. What is the other one you are referring to. Could please upload another screenshot?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you! do you know how i can make the text area to show only for the specific list that is being clicked on?